# Is there a standard notation for arrows to terminal objects?

Tags: category-theory, notation

Let $1$ denote a terminal object. By definition, for any object $X$, there is a unique arrow $f : X \rightarrow 1$. Is there any standard notation for this arrow? Maybe it would be something like $T_X : X \rightarrow 1$ ($T$ for terminal)? I haven't seen such a notation in my category theory references.

Comment: You can denote it by $!$ or simply omit naming it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the unique morphism into a product, the notation $\langle f_1, \ldots, f_n \rangle : X \to A_1 \times \cdots \times A_n$ is often used, in which case the unique morphism into the terminal object would be denoted $\langle\rangle : X \to 1$. You can write $\langle\rangle_X$ to make the object explicit. In practice, however, I find that this notation is less commonly encountered in the nullary case than the binary case. Sometimes you'll also encounter $! : X \to 1$ or $!_X : X \to 1$, since $!$ is often used to denote unique elements.

In a diagram, one can omit a name for the morphism entirely, since it is unique. However, this is not convenient for equational reasoning.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I personally like $\langle \rangle_X$ best, since it really follows logically from the rest of the established notation, and doesn't require the use of a new symbol.